# String manipulation by C language function of PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I'd like to create a postgresql c-Language function whose arguments and return values are varchar and which uses Char [] during processing.

But, it does not work as expected.

I made a program of c like this.

```c
#include <postgres.h>
#include <port.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

// Required for windows.
extern PGDLLEXPORT Datum VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR);

Datum VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    // Get arg.
    VarChar  *arg1 = (VarChar *)PG_GETARG_VARCHAR_P(0);

    // VarChar to Char[].
    char *c = (char *)VARDATA(arg1);

    elog(NOTICE, "VarChar to Char[]."); 
    elog(NOTICE, c);//Log1

    // Do something.(e.g. replace)
    // Since it uses another system, it must be Char [].

    //Char[] to VarChar.
    VarChar *rtn = (VarChar *)VARDATA(c);
    elog(NOTICE, "Char[] to VarChar.");
    elog(NOTICE, rtn);//Log2

    // Return VarChar.
    PG_RETURN_VARCHAR_P(rtn);
}
```

And, created such a script.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR(character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
'$libdir/test/VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR.dll', 'VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT;
```

The execution result is like this.

```sql
SELECT VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR('a');
-- Expected value: 'a'
-- Postgresql terminated abnormally... :(

SELECT VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR('Action');
-- Expected return value: 'Action'
-- Actual return value  :'n'
-- Log1  :'NOTICE:  n'
-- Log2  :''

SELECT VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR('ActionAction');
-- Expected return value: 'ActionAction'
-- Actual return value  : ''  <-Why?
-- Log1  :''
-- Log2  :''

SELECT VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR('Action Action');
-- Expected return value: 'Action Action'
-- Actual return value  : 'n Action'
-- Log1  :'NOTICE:  Action Action'
-- Log2  :'NOTICE:  ction'

SELECT VARCHAR_CHAR_ARRAY_VARCHAR('1234567890');
-- Expected return value: '1234567890'
-- Actual return value  : '6789'
-- Log1  :'NOTICE:  1234567890'
-- Log2  :'NOTICE:  90'
```

#### Execution environment:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 x64
- PostgreSQL 9.5.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

I'm using C language for the first time, so I'm glad to present sample code.

I'm sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: ***How*** does it "not work as expected"? You show us the actual results but what are the *expected* results? Please [(re-)read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I added an expected value.
Anyway, if the input value is return as it is OK.

(It is mandatory that it is internally converted to char [].)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually constructing a `text` or `VarChar` like that won't work. You can't just

```
VarChar *rtn = (VarChar *)VARDATA(c);
```

because what you're doing there is trying to interpret  the `char*` value `c` as if it were a `VarChar*`, reading the first few bytes as a `VARLENA` header, and then getting some substring within it as the value. Not going to work.

It's *much* easier to use `cstring_to_text` and `text_to_cstring` to convert. `text*` is exactly compatible with `VarChar*`. (They're in `utils/builtins.h`).

e.g.

```
 PG_RETURN_VARCHAR_P(cstring_to_text(c));
```

To do it manually, have to `palloc` a string with `strlen`  bytes + `VARHDRSIZE`, `SET_VARSIZE`, then `strcpy` the data to the `VARDATA` offset. See `src/include/utils/varlena.h` and `src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`. It's fiddly and not necessary when PostgreSQL has helper functions for the purpose.

Personally I recommend ignoring `varchar` completely for C-level programming. Define your functions as accepting and returning `text`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I could not find cstring_from_text.
Perhaps, is text_to_cstring?